# error with interpSpline function

Tags: r

I have a  list of data frames, xyz, and in every data frame there are 2 numeric vectors (x and y). I want to apply the interpSpline function from package splines to x and y, but when I do :

```
lapply(xyz, function (x){
x%>%
interpSpline(x,y)
})
```

I get the following error:

> Error in data.frame(x = as.numeric(obj1), y = as.numeric(obj2)) :
>   (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `interpSpline` doesn't take a data frame as its first argument.

```
xyz <- list(data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10)),
            data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10)))
library(splines)
sf <- function(d) with(d,interpSpline(x,y)))
s <- lapply(xyz,sf)
```

You could also use `interpSpline(d$x,d$y)`.  It *might* be possible to do enough contortions to get `interpSpline` to work with pipes, but it hardly seems worth the trouble ...

Comment: I have tried to use your suggestion, but now I have another error that says:

"Error in interpSpline.default(d$x, x$y) : 
  values of 'x' must be distinct"

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment on Ben's answer, `interpSpline()` requires the input x values to be unique. So, to avoid this error you could use the `spline()` function instead of `interpSpline()`. This will set `s` equal to the interpolated values of the spline at each x,y input coordinate.  However, you will not have all the other output that you get from `interpSpline()`.

```
set.seed(1)
# fake up some data that has duplicate 'x' values
xyz <- list(data.frame(x=round(rnorm(100),1),y=round(rnorm(100),1)),
            data.frame(x=round(rnorm(100),1),y=round(rnorm(100),1)))
library(splines)
sf <- function(d) with(d,spline(x,y))
s <- lapply(xyz,sf)
```